# Error "No function matches the . . ." Laravel Transaction With PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

I using laravel 5.3 with PostgreSQL and i have code like this

```
public function store(array $request)
{
    DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
        $phoneData = [
            'phone_no' => $request['phone'],
            'created_by' => $request['sdm_employee_id'],
            'updated_by' => $request['sdm_employee_id'],
            'created_stamp' => Carbon::now()->toDateString(),
            'updated_stamp' => Carbon::now()->toDateString(),
        ];

        $phone = DonorPhone::create($phoneData);
        if (!$phone) {
            throw new \Exception('Phone not created for account');
        }

        $data = [
            'phone_id' => $phone->id,
            'full_name' => $request['name'],
            'address' => $request['address'],
            'email' => array_key_exists('email', $request) ? $request['email'] : null,
            'register_date' => Carbon::now()->toDateString(),
            'marketer_id' => (int) $request['sdm_employee_id'],
            'created_by' => (int) $request['sdm_employee_id'],
            'updated_by' => (int) $request['sdm_employee_id'],
            'company_id' => 2,
            'user_status' => 1,
            'note' => 'Add donor from sales track apps',
            'phone_no_full' => $request['phone'],
            'created_stamp' => Carbon::now()->toDateString(),
            'updated_stamp' => Carbon::now()->toDateString(),
        ];

        $contact = self::create($data);
        if (!$contact) {
            throw new \Exception('Contact not created');
        }

        $phone->user_id = (int)$contact->id;
        $phone->save();

        $target = new Target;
        $target->updateAchievement($data['sdm_employee_id'], $this->tragetType, Carbon::now()->year, Carbon::now()->month);

        throw new \Exception('Contact not created');
    });
}
```

When create contact i got error

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function php_donor_phone_get_all(integer) does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT php_donor_phone_get_all(NEW.id)\n               ^\nHINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.\nQUERY:  SELECT php_donor_phone_get_all(NEW.id)\nCONTEXT:  PL\/pgSQL function public.php_donor_tr_full_text() line 6 at assignment (SQL: insert into \"public\".\"php_donor_personal\" (\"full_name\", \"address\", \"email\", \"register_date\", \"marketer_id\", \"created_by\", \"updated_by\", \"company_id\", \"user_status\", \"phone_no_full\", \"created_stamp\", \"updated_stamp\") values . . .
```

I check for function php_donor_phone_get_all is exist and my database username have a grant to execute this function. This seems to relate to a specific data type when calling the function, passing not an integer, but I do not know how to ensure that data in passing is an integer. There is a hint for me? Please help.

Comment: Show us the `php_donor_phone_get_all` function

Comment: @chalithageekiyanage this http://pastebin.com/JM6Nvizt

Comment: Did your function code executed successfully?  Because you haven't mentioned the language that you are using

Comment: Here I have an example of the same process, create contact but using Yii 2 and that no errors occurred.